# How to display result of javascript as HTML link?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have the following code that I use to retrieve the hostname of a server and append some text (a filename) to it and display it on an html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getBaseUrl() {
        var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(getBaseUrl() + "filename.ext");
</script>
```

That generates a server URL such as https://fqdn/folder/filename.ext which is exactly what I need.  Everything I have tried to create a link from it breaks things.  How do I make that generated text clickable?

Comment: "I have tried to create a link from it breaks things" - Please show us  how you tried to create the link and explain what it broke and how it broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, I assume getBaseUrl() is working although this doesn't look like. Just a reminder that `<a>` tag needs to be under the `<script>` block

```
<script>
    function getBaseUrl() {
        var re = new RegExp(/^.*\//);
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:" onclick="location.href=getBaseUrl() + 'filename.ext'">Click</a>
```

Comment: I never accepted the answer!  Apologies!  I went back and found the code and this was the answer that most looked like what I implemented.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to wrap it in an `<a href=''></a>`. This is easiest if you assign the `<a>` element in question to a variable, as you can then use **[`.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href)** to modify the link, along with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** to modify the text:

```js
function getBaseUrl() {
  return 'http://www.google.com/';
}

const output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = 'Link Title';
output.href = getBaseUrl() + "filename.ext";
```

```html
<a id="output" href=""></a>
```

If you don't have access to the HTML, this can still be done with raw JavaScript by simply including the `<a href=''></a>` wrapper in your output, being careful to also output the single quotes:

```js
function getBaseUrl() {
  return 'http://www.google.com/';
}

document.write("<a href='" + getBaseUrl() + "filename.ext" + "'>Link Title</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward to do -

```
const link = getBaseUrl()+ "filename.ext";

createLinkNode(link, document.body);

// defining a function to create a link node, however this isn't neccessary,
// you could just hard code the logic above.
// I wouldn't recommend setting innerHtml in lieu of making a text node however.
function createLinkNode(url, parent) {
  const linkTextNode = document.createTextNode(url);
  const linkNode = document.createElement('a');
  linkNode.href = url;
  linkNode.appendChild(linkTextNode);

  parent.appendChild(linkNode);
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/f4wxvLky/3/

Comment: This is doing exactly what I want!  Thank you.  I am having a heck of a time getting the link to show up in the proper place.  Keeps getting thrown at the bottom of the page rather than in any of my <div class>'s.  Any ideas?

Comment: The call to createLinkNode should be updated - instead of document.body you can use document.querySelector to get the proper DOM element to append to.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Got it!  Thank you so much!  Learning a little more javascript each day. :)